# Parent directory's gulpfile forces working directory change despite local gulpfile

Tags: node.js, gulp, zurb-foundation

I am developing a website that uses gulp to assist with development. I have a structure that looks similar to:

- Main Project Folder

  - `gulpfile.js`
  - UI Toolkit Folder

    - `gulpfile.js`
  - Zurb's "Foundation For Emails" project folder

    - `gulpfile.babel.js`

When in the directory for Zurb's "Foundation for Emails", if I attempt to run any of the following:

- `npm start`
- `foundation watch`
- `npm run build`

PowerShell says: "Changing working directory" and then runs the default gulp task in my Main Project folder. This does not happen when I run gulp commands from my UI Toolkit Folder.

However, if I delete the `gulpfile.js` in my Main Project Folder, all three of those commands work as expected. What's happening? How can I make these commands work with a `gulpfile.js` file in its parent's directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `package.json` in your Foundaton For Emails folder and add the `--gulpfile gulpfile.babel.js` option to all of your npm scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "gulp --gulpfile gulpfile.babel.js",
  "build": "gulp --gulpfile gulpfile.babel.js --production",
  "zip": "gulp --gulpfile gulpfile.babel.js zip --production",
  "litmus": "gulp --gulpfile gulpfile.babel.js litmus --production"
},
```

This forces gulp to use the correct gulpfile instead of traversing the directory hierarchy upwards.